# Show convergence of $x_n$ if $x_n$ is bounded and lim sup $x_n$ ⩽ $x_n$ for almost every n

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

Im stucked on proofing that

If $x_n$ is bounded and lim sup $x_n$ ⩽ $x_n$ for almost every n, then $x_n$ converges.

Similary how would i show that this doesn't hold for every n?

Any help or hint how to approach a solution is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Hint :** If $\limsup x_n \leq x_n$ for almost every $n$, then $\limsup x_n \leq \liminf x_n$.

Comment: I guess since $x_n$ is bounded $\implies \liminf x_n \leq \limsup x_n$ and 

if $\limsup x_n \leq x_n$ for almost every n, then $\limsup x_n \leq \liminf x_n$.

However if that's the case then,  $\limsup x_n \leq \liminf x_n$ can only hold true, if  $\liminf x_n = \limsup x_n$, which
would mean that $x_n$ converges.

The only thing left, would be to show that if $\limsup x_n \leq x_n$ for almost every n, then $\limsup x_n \leq \liminf x_n$ (as you stated). 
Is that right so far?